# CakePHP and MD5 login system

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, md5, cakephp-2.3

For CakePHP application I have to use MD5 algorithm for storing login passwords.

Problem I have is that I can not convert properly submitted login password to md5.

For example, if password is euro, it's md5 is 2acae8be44a70913481e66dd2cd3f761

But CakePHP convert it into f85378844044678d28f1a1f306d4af50, and due to that users cannot login into application (or I guess that is a problem).

To enable MD5 passwords, into AppControler I added:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    Security::setHash('md5');
}
```

Also, I tried to check login function with:

```
function login() {

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

        pr(AuthComponent::password($this->data['Company']['password']));
        // this returns f85378844044678d28f1a1f306d4af50

        // etc...

    }

}
```

Can you give me please some clues what I'm doing wrong with this? I must use MD5 in this case.

Comment: Probably because you have set `salt` in your boostrap.php, so in your case it will be `md5($salt.$password)` not `md5($password)`  look in `lib/Cake/Utils/Security`, you could set `$salt` to `null` <- not recommended

Comment: Nope, there is no variable $salt (or even word salt) in boostrap.php

Comment: check value of Security.salt. for example: `debug(Configure::read('Security.salt'));`

Comment: It's in core.php, search for Security.salt

Comment: **Don't** use md5 it is insecure. http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure

Answer (score 0):

In this code your Encrypt password with `md5` and comparing  with `AuthComponent::password()` these both are different  different method use `AuthComponent::password()` in both case.

Here is an example how to use:-

Add Following lines of code in your model.
Use auth component for authpassword

```
App::uses('SimplePasswordHasher', 'Controller/Component/Auth');
```

Add Code in Before save function to encrypt password :-

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
$this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = AuthComponent::password(
$this->data[$this->alias]['password']
);
}
return true;
}
```

Use this function of model to compare password :-

```
public function checkCurrentPassword($data) {
$this->id = AuthComponent::user('id');
$password = $this->field('password');
return(AuthComponent::password($data['current_password']) == $password);
}
```

Comment: MD5 is a form of hashing, not encryption, hashing cannot be reversed.